# errno -4058 ENOENT: no such file or directory This is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

D:\react> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\react/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-04T06_09_25_519Z-debug.log

I am a beginner , I have my node installed in C: drive but I Want to create a react project in D: drive . project was created but when I ran 'npm start' it gave me Error.
npm ERR! This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Answer (score 0):

Opened command prompt as an administrator and and changed my directories to d drive and reached to my folder . then  created project and ran " npm start " from command prompt .it worked . so just I had to open project as an administrator.

follow below steps :

```
 C:\Windows\system32>cd..
C:\Windows>cd..
C:\>d:
D:\>cd react
D:\react>npx create-react-app my-app
```

your project will be created. then go to project folder

D:\react>cd my-app

D:\react\my-app>`npm start`

> // plz don't type above quotation mark.

now my project ran into the browser. I Hope it helps to others as well.